# 2D Fourier transform of annulus

Tags: fourier-analysis, integral-transforms

I have an annulus and I'd like to the take the 2D Fourier transform of it, my code:

```
a[x_, y_] := 1 < (x^2 + y^2) <= 2
RegionPlot[a[x, y], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}]
```

I have tried `FourierTransform` and `Fourier` and they do nothing.

Am I doing something visibly stupid and wrong?

Comment: It's a little unclear what you mean by the Fourier transform of a region. Are you trying to do the 2D Fourier transform of the piecewise defined function `a[x_, y_] = Piecewise[{{1, 1 < (x^2 + y^2) <= 2}, {0, True}}]`? Or are you trying to do the Fourier transform of a *constant* over that region (like, if you're computing the far-field diffraction pattern created by light passing through an annular aperture)? Or something else?

Comment: Just change from cartesian to polar coordinates and do `HankelTransfrom`

Comment: Just an FYI, `RegionPlot` returns a graphics object that is a polygonal representation of the input, and is meant for visualization only.

Comment: My Mathematica (11.0) does not recognise HankelTransform as a command. It's not even in the help documentation! What could be the reason?

Comment: Solved!I went to 11.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define your region as a Piecewise function (as suggested by march) and then apply FourierTransform:

```
a[x_, y_] := Piecewise[{{1, 1 < (x^2 + y^2) <= 2}, {0, True}}];
FourierTransform[a[x, y], {x, y}, {u, v}]
```

[image]

You may want to check to make sure that the FourierParameters are using the definition you are used to.

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying it but its takes ages to do the FT. Is there any way of speeding it up?

Comment: Its a bit faster if you use set instead of set delayed ("=" instead of ":="). If it is taking longer than a few seconds, then restart the kernel because something is wrong.

Comment: I'm doing:<code>ring[x_, y_] = Piecewise[{{1,1<(x^2+y^2)<=2}, {0, True}] </code>, then <code>ft[u,v] = FourierTransform[ring[x,y],{x,y},{u,v}]</code>, it takes ages and it does not return anything! Anything wrong wiht me?

Comment: Start with a fresh session (quit the kernel), copy paste the code above as it is, and you will get the answer I just pasted after a few seconds.

Comment: Yes that's what I did... I'll try on a different machine tomorrow... Which version of Mathematica are you on by the way?

Comment: I'm using MMa 11.2 on a mac, though these seem pretty stable commands, so I doubt version should make much difference. Maybe someone else will try...

Comment: MMa meaning Mathematica or some other expanded package? I'm afraid there is something wrong with my Mathematica. a) it does not recognise HankelTransform as a command, b) it only computes the FourierTransform of Cos[x] and simple functions, but if I give it Exp[-r] for example it does nothing...

Comment: Solved!I went to 11.2.